# viewpager image swipes first sound from array not played

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have made this app. Here used viewpager to image swipe & playing sound which matches the image. Now it is working fine but only problem is on first page image it not playing sound because page is not swipe on start up. How do i solve this problem?.. This is my code

```
public class Learning_Numbers extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    MediaPlayer BG;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_numbers);
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(player);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        BG = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jingle);
        BG.setLooping(true);
        BG.setVolume(100, 100);
        BG.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        BG.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        BG.start();
    }

    private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.one,R.raw.two,R.raw.three,R.raw.four,R.raw.five,R.raw.six,R.raw.seven,R.raw.eight,R.raw.nine,R.raw.ten};

    private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.no1,R.drawable.no2,R.drawable.no3,R.drawable.no4,R.drawable.no5,R.drawable.no6,R.drawable.no7,R.drawable.no8,R.drawable.no9,R.drawable.no10};

 OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0)
        {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Learning_Numbers.this, mAudio[arg0]);
            mp.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
        {
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put below code after `myPager.setCurrentItem(0);` in `onCreate()`:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(Learning_Numbers.this, mAudio[0]);
mp.start();
```

Hope it will work..!!!